# Angular md-erroor only work when clicked

Tags: angular

right now `md-error` works when the page is loaded and input bar is typed, but I want to activate it only when "add" button is clicked. If you could give advices, it would be so helpfull.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms'
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public details: [Detail];

  sample = new FormControl('',[
    Validators.required,
  ])

  myForm = this.builder.group({
    sample: this.sample
  });

constructor(
  private builder:FormBuilder,
  private MdInputModule: MdInputModule
){}

addDetail(){
  if(this.sample.errors !==null){
    console.log("データないよ")
  }else
  {console.log(this.sample.value)}
}

onSave(){}

ngOnInit() {}

}

class Detail{
  public sample : FormControl;
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <input mdInput type="number" required placeholder="数量" [formControl] ="sample"/>
        <md-error *ngIf="this.sample.errors?.required">
        　need to inform.
        </md-error>
    <div class="footer-div">
        <button md-raised-button (click)="addDetail();">add</button>
        <button md-raised-button (click)="onSave();">save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a variable call `submitted` in you typescript and set it to `false`.
then use `(change)` on your input, like this:

```
<input mdInput type="number" (change)="submitted=false".
       required placeholder="数量" [formControl] ="sample"/>
```

on you `addDetail()` method add: `this.submitted = true;`
then in your md-error add:

```
<md-error *ngIf="this.sample.errors?.required && submitted">
　need to inform.
</md-error>
```

so everytime the input value changes, its assumed that you didn't submitted yet. Then, when you submit, you set you variable to `true` and the `*ngIf` will evaluate both conditions

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: thank you for the advice, I understand the concept and it is very helpful.